# CSS -- Creating sub classes

Tags: css

I have a default style for my input boxes.  I would like to add an additional style to the box when I specify a class of "req".  It's not working.  Here's my code.

CSS:

```
input{background-color: #000; color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #515151; width: 230px;}
input req {background-color: Purple;}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="FirstName" type="text" class="req" />
```

The textbox reflects the input class, but not the sub class.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your CSS stylesheet, change:

```
input req { ... }
```

to:

```
input.req { ... }
```

(`input.req` denotes all `input` elements that belong to class `req`, while `input req` denotes all `req` elements that are inside an `input` element. The dot prefixed class name is merely [shorthand for the `[class~=req]` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need a dot between my base input class and my sub class.

```
input.req {background-color: Purple;}
```

Comment: Yes, this is because "input req" means "the child of input that is of type req" and "input.req" means "the thing that is an input and has the class req".  "." means "class" and "#" means "id".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot from class name, try this:

```
input.req {background-color: Purple;}
```

Or simply add this style because you are already using this for your textbox:

```
.req {background-color: Purple;}
```